# Futurama, birther movement parody and a southern border wall reference

Tags: futurama

I'm rewatching this season of Futurama. In Futurama Season 7, episode 3, aired on June 27th, 2012, there is episode, and a part that I copied from subtitles:

"Decision 3012" is the third episode of the seventh season of the animated sitcom Futurama. It originally aired on Comedy Central on June 27, 2012. The plot is a parody of the Birther Movement.  (Wikipedia)

I understand the birtherism part of the parody, but I don't understand where this comes from  -- at that time (2011 / 2012):

> 00:01:42,371 --> 00:01:43,914
>
> Who here is tired
>
> 00:01:44,039 --> 00:01:46,784
>
> of illegal space aliens
>
> taking our good earth jobs?
>
> 00:01:48,733 --> 00:01:50,054
>
> Me, too.
>
> 00:01:50,179 --> 00:01:52,623
>
> So, if I'm reelected,
>
> I promise to build
>
> 00:01:52,748 --> 00:01:54,892
>
> a really big Dyson fence
>
> 00:01:55,017 --> 00:01:57,534
>
> across the Southern border
>
> of our solar system.

Listening to it now clearly sounds like a parody of Trump, but I can only find references to a 2016 campaigning Trump talking about a southern border wall.

The earliest reference of Trump's wall I've found on Wikipedia is 26th March 2016.

Can you explain this line to me from a 2012 perspective ?

Comment: People have been mooting a big fence for decades, noting that the current little fence is almost entirely ineffective

Comment: @Valorum Indeed, I remember playing a board game called _[Fortress America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortress_America_(board_game))_ back in the 80's, and when I remarked how preposterous the whole thing was, the other players looked at me as if I'd just grown another head.

Comment: Twist: the Birther Movement was a parody of Futurama.

Answer (score 2):

Illegal immigrants coming and "taking" jobs has been a thing for a very long time as well as drug smuggling and other reasons to illegally cross a border is a political issue and the episode is a political parody of sorts.

One explanation is that the cartoon gave trump ideas.

A more serious answer is the US government has maintained a wall of sorts across the southern border for around 3 decades its effectiveness is debatable but its cost is a matter of public record, government overspending is humorous to some.